# Python3 comparing row by row values from csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using python3.5

After importing my csv file I want these operations:
IN:

```
ULIM LLIM High Low CLO $RNG U-OCT MID L-OCT
-------------------------------------------

12785 125300 127840 127500 127475 1275 127532 126575 125618
```

OUT:

```
Dir ULIM LLIM High Low CLO $RNG U-OCT MID L-OCT Test
----------------------------------------------------

S   12785 125300 127840 127500 127475 1275 127532 126575 125618 T
```

add TWO New Colums: Direction and Test

T= IF CLO or High or Low values within either U-OCT to ULIM range or L-OCT to LLIM range values
   else no entry

S= L if CLO above MID, S if CLOS below MID

This is what I want to learn/need help for:

I don't know how to do the comparing part and adding the results in the new two colums. (arrays?)
I don't know how to do that for the whole csv table (looping?)

Comment: Hi El, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide the input and output data  in question as text instead of image.

Comment: Learn from here https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Tahnk you Rahul, but this article doesent help me with my problem. I know how to import/save csv files. What I dont know is how to grap the specefic values in the rows to do the math operations.

Comment: I think I have to write the rows first and then grap the values from the rows. But how do I get the specific value in the row and do that for all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each line and check from the retrieved dictionary like this:

```
import csv

output = open('csv_file_out.txt', 'w')
with open('csv_file.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=' ')
    T = False
    S = 'S'
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i > 0:
            if row['CLO'] > row['MID']:
                S = 'L'
            if row['U-OCT'] <= row['CLO'] <= row['ULIM']:
                T = True

            writer.writerow([S, row['CLO'], row['ULIM'], row['LLIM'], 'T' if T else ''])
```

You have to update the rules according to want you want though. Also, you could find cleaner way for writer.writerow() but I'm not that familiar.